# Why does "Please approve it" sound wrong?

Tags: pronouns, word-usage, email

Whenever I read an email like this, the English sounds incorrect to me.

"I would like to take tomorrow off. Please approve it."

I want to say that "Please approve" is more natural, but why is that?

Comment: "It" is being used as a neutral pronoun, almost like a placeholder for something, which in this case is your request to take tomorrow off.  But why can't you just say "Please approve my request"?

Comment: The English is not incorrect, but it is perhaps, impolite despite the use of *please* because it is formed as a command.

Comment: "Please, could you give your approval" sounds more polite and, perhaps, more natural. But it is wordier; in emails, requests and inquiries among the workforce should be concise.

Comment: Perhaps the 'oddness' that you feel with this structure is because it would work better as a single sentence. E.g., "I would like to take tomorrow off; please approve it?" I personally find "Please approve" worse.

Comment: "I would like to request tomorrow off.  Please approve it." or "I would like to request tomorrow off.  Could you please approve it?" would both be (to me) better wordings; the latter also seeming more polite being phrased as a question/request rather than a [polite] demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, I can't be sure why it sounds wrong *to you*, but to me it sounds a bit funny because I'm expecting "it" to refer back to something mentioned previously, and the only thing in the previous sentence it seems it could refer to is "tomorrow".  And asking someone to "approve tomorrow" is just silly — there will be a tomorrow whether they approve it or not.

A minimal fix would be either to drop the "it", as you suggest — which would make the sentence somewhat terse and elliptical, but which could work in a workplace e-mail — or to replace it with "this", which at least could validly refer to the entire request.  But just to avoid ambiguity, I'd prefer to expand it all the way to "this request", as suggested by trpt4him.

Or, alternatively, the request could be rephrased e.g. as:

> "I would like to take a day off tomorrow. Please approve it."

where "it" can now refer to "a day off" (viewed as a set phrase), which can be legitimately approved.

(Ps. I make no comment on whether the brevity of the request is appropriate here, since that doesn't seem to be what you're asking about and since I'm not familiar with your local workplace communications style.  In some places and contexts, your example request might be exactly as long as it needs to be; in others, you might have to expand it to five times its current length to make sure it sounds polite and respectful enough.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native speaker, so I might be biased, but ...

```
I would like to take tomorrow off. Please approve it.
```

... you're not *asking* for approval, you're *telling* the other end that you intend to take tomorrow off, and that s/he is expected (by you) to approve at once. This is probably why it sounds wrong.

Changing it as suggested to

```
I would like to take tomorrow off. Please approve it ?
```

Doesn't sound better: it's like the writer is begging for approval.

To keep it short and convey the actual request, I'd choose different wording:

```
I'd like to take tomorrow off. Do you approve ?
```

or

```
I request permission to take tomorrow off.
```

Answer (score 0):

*May I have tomorrow off?*

No need to strain to use other modal verbs; we have one that addresses what is allowed, perfect for polite requests like these.

One can probably extrapolate that you want tomorrow off, if you are asking. If you need to explain the good reason, be specific.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds a lot better and would be more polite to say 'Please would you approve it?' It just sounds too terse for what is a request.